# Would this message in my terminal prevent my rails backend from loading objects in my DB as a fetch request?

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-3, backend

Started POST "/recipes" for ::1 at 2022-01-20 22:48:13 -0500
(0.7ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
(0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'create' could not be found for RecipesController):

actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:131:in `process' actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in` dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch' actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in` dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve' actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in` block in serve'
actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each' actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in` serve'
actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call' rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in` call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call' rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in` call'
activerecord (6.0.4.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call' actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in` block in call'
activesupport (6.0.4.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks' actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in` call'
actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call' actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in` call'
actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call' actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in` call'
railties (6.0.4.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app' railties (6.0.4.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in` block in call'
activesupport (6.0.4.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged' activesupport (6.0.4.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in` tagged'
activesupport (6.0.4.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged' railties (6.0.4.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in` call'
actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call' actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in` call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call' activesupport (6.0.4.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in` call'
actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call' actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in` call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call' actionpack (6.0.4.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:103:in` call'
rack-cors (1.1.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:100:in `call' railties (6.0.4.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in` call'
puma (4.3.10) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call' puma (4.3.10) lib/puma/server.rb:718:in` handle_request'
puma (4.3.10) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client' puma (4.3.10) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in` block in run'
puma (4.3.10) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The objects in my seed file are not loading on my UI. I have a rails backend and React frontend